# Change kernel config without compiling

Tags: kernel

Is it possible to change the kernel configuration of the running kernel without compiling it myself?

In debian-based systems, there's the config file of the current kernel in /boot, e.g. `/boot/config-3.13.0-37-generic`.

Would merely changing this file change the kernel config? Or would I have to compile the kernel in order to apply these changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to compile the kernel. The `/boot/config-3.13.0-37-generic` is simply the kernel config file at the time of compilation; it is there so that you know what has been compiled into your kernel and as a starting point for your own compilations.

It's not so difficult to do it --- the worst part of kernel compiling is the configuration; there are literally thousands of options.

Been there, [done that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104177/52205); trying to stay away unless really needed...